# Extract the symmetric matrix built-in another matrix

Tags: matrix

Suppose that I have a matrix `M`:

```
M={
   {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
   {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
   {1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
   {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}
  };
```

I like to extract from `M` the symmetric matrix `symM`:

```
symM={
      {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
      {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
      {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
     };
```

I do not want to use `Do` or `If` commands. I like to implement matrix operations to extract the symmetric part of `M`.

**EDIT 1**

In general terms, matrix `M` is composed of `1` and `0` only, with the condition that the diagonal cells be `zeros`. My goal is to extract the matrix `symM` which should only include `1`s in the non-zero reciprocal cells (or symmetric cells), otherwise `zero`.

Example, in the above example, `M[[1,2]]=1` and `M[[2,1]]=1`, then both `symM[[1,2]]` and `symM[[2,1]]` should be `1`. All other cells which are not qualified should be all `zero`.

I hope the question is clearer now. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a particular algorithm in mind?

Comment: @corey979: I do not have any algorithm in mind but maybe `Scan` can be used to collect the non-negative symmetric positions in `M`.

Comment: `BitAnd[M, Transpose[M]]`

Comment: @Coolwater That's a good one! Why don't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. I interpreted your question as if you want to replace all nonsymmetric entries of the input matrix by zeroes and as if the input matrix is not necessarily binary.

```
A = M Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[Transpose[M], M]]];
```

Comment: Yes...That is what I wanted to have. Perfect...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher For the symmetric part of M I would have expected  something like `(M+Transpose[M])/2`...Interestingly your result fullfills `A==Floor[(M+Transpose[M])/2]` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `(M+Transpose[M])/2` is the symmetrized part, and in particular the orthogonal projection onto the linear space of symmetric matrices (orthogonal with respect to the Frobenius metric). But as by OP's examples, this was not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Henrik: Referring to your last point, you are right that your `code` gives me what I wanted. I checked it with other examples and it works.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a bit simpler:

```
M Transpose[M]
```

Comparing with Henrik's answer:

```
M Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[Transpose[M], M]]] == M Transpose[M]
True
```

Comment: Simpler indeed. But it will work only for binary matrices. Well, actually, it is still somewhat unclear, what the OP's usage spectrum and desired result in the general case is supposed to be. I interpreted it as if the OP wants to replace all nonsymmetric entries of the input matrix by zeroes.

Comment: @Henrik -- Agreed, I took the binary example suggested by the OP as indicating interest only in binary matrices.

Comment: @Henrik: I wanted to extract binary cells only: that is, if `(i,j)==(j,i)==1`, then keep them in the output matrix, otherwise place `zeros` to both cells. What you are saying in your comment is what I actually wanted: `replace all non-symmetric entries of the input matrix with zeros`. Is Bill's proposal equivalent to your proposal? I want to make sure this because in the original case with `n=1000` I cannot check  it visually.

Comment: A simple example for which bill's and my proposals lead to different output is the matrix `M = {{1, 2},{1,1}}`. In general it is preferrable to post also all assumptions on the input data already in the question. Moreover your question leave a lot room for interpretation. Please specify exactly what the desired output for a general input matrix should be.

Comment: @Henrik: I will edit the question in line with your comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
A = Floor @ Symmetrize @ M;

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ A
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Note: This is much slower than the methods in the answers by bill s and  Henrik Schumacher.

Comment: Your answer showed me a mistake in my `symM` in the original post. Somehow the `symM` matrix was not symmetric (I do not know how I did this typo). but now the `symM` is correct, thanks to your post.